# How can I make ls show information about the directory specified only, not info about its sub-files or folder contents?

Tags: directory, ls

Say I have folder "foo" residing, the home directory. I want to get some info of it, owner, group, permissions, etc...

I then do this to try to get the information:

```
cd ~
ls -l foo
```

Of course it now lists the info of the contents of "foo"

Then I could do something like this

```
cd ~
dir=foo
ls -l $foo/.. | awk 'BEGIN { dir="'$foo'" } { if($9 == dir) { print $0 }  }'
```

But isn't there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try

```
ls -ld foo
```

And you will get what you want.

But also consider `stat` if you want to capture information. The output of `ls` is for human consumption only.

```
stat -c %U foo # get owner of foo
```