# How to display directory permission without listing permission for their contents

Tags: directory, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make ls show information about the directory specified only, not info about its sub-files or folder contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19022/how-can-i-make-ls-show-information-about-the-directory-specified-only-not-info)

I am new to UNIX and I want to display the permission for several directories without listing the permission for the files inside those directories.

I have the following directories - each of this directories contains a file inside them, for example  :

```
Directory1
File1
Directory2
File2
Directory3
File3
```

I am using this command to list directories and their files : `ls di*` what should I add to this command to list the files permission of the directories without listing the files permissions?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `-d` option for ls, only the directory entries will be displayed. From the `ls` manpage:

```
   -d, --directory
          list directory entries instead of contents, and do not  derefer
          ence symbolic links
```

For your example:

```
ls -ld Di*
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, using command `ls -ld di*` result in `/usr/bin/ls: No match`

Comment: @JohnSmith - Updated to match your example directory names.

Comment: thanks, it works. using this command instead of the `ls -l` just doesnt display the `total #` is that how you know the permissions are only for the directories and not the files?